# Why does English not have a cognate of words like heter, in Swedish, or llama, in Spanish, etc?

Tags: english, germanic-languages, romance-languages, names

This is something that I *think* is present in most languages. If I were to present my self in English, I might say:

> My name is DisplayName.

Where as in other languages I can both say:

> Mitt namn är DisplayName

Or I could use heter like this:

> Jag heter DisplayName.

Or in Icelandic, "nafn mitt er DisplayName", or "Ég heiti DisplayName", or in Spanish it would be "me llamo DisplayName".

Why is there no such English word? Has it ever existed? (Old English, Middle English) etc.

Comment: In Spanish, llamar means call. Llamarse is a reflexive version of it. Me llamo means "they call me...". It's just convention.

Comment: @Atamari Oh yes, im bad at spanish but thats still true to the meaning.

Comment: We use the passive of "call" or "name"; many languages do.

Comment: It's just a similar difference as between "I like it" and "eso me gusta". The phrases differ in their argument structure. You could say "it pleases me", it's just not common. Many things in language are arbitrary.

Comment: The English "I call myself Daniel," is a direct translation of the Spanish "Me llamo Daniel," although it would be strange to use this construction to introduce oneself.

Comment: I suppose it could be due to the fact that in common law countries one's name is actually determined by what one calls oneself. In most germanic language speaking countries some form of civil law applies and one's legal name is not determined by how one is called but by how one was named. - So that may be the answer to "why?"

Comment: In Spain it is becoming more common to use the expression "soy name" I am name

Comment: @DisplayName: What do you mean by "version"? That's not a technical term in linguistics. You mean a cognate of the words you give in other Germanic languages. But the word you give in Spanish is not a cognate of those, so do you just mean "translation"? And then are you strictly looking for a single word because translation also takes into account morphology, syntax, semantics, etc.

Comment: Amusingly, native speakers of Hindi (and a number of related languages) who have English as an L2 will sometimes use the construction "I am called as Singh" or similar. I guess this is probably calqued from Hindi/etc.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Your question does not make it clear to the reader (particularly one such as myself, unfamiliar with the languages you quote) exactly what it is that you perceive as being the difference in these two phrasings.
There are many ways of saying what your name is, in every language. What specific nuance are you aiming for?

Comment: It's also true in Hebrew. You could say "השם שלי דיספלי-שם" (My name is DisplayName), or you could say "קוראים לי דיספלי-שם" (They call me DisplayName).  In my experience, both versions are in common usage.

Comment: "Call me Ishmael".  "My name is Michael, but you can call me Mike".

Answer (score 44, accepted):

English does have that verb which is etymologically related to the Swedish *heter*, Icelandic *heiti*, German *heißen*, etc. In English it is [*to hight*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hight#English), only it is archaic, still sometimes it *is* used nowadays, mostly in poetry, for example in the 1943 poem [I hight Don Quixote, I live on peyote](http://hermetic.com/parsons/i-hight-don-quixote-i-live-on-peyote.html) by John Whiteside “Jack” Parsons, or in the name of the modern punk rock song [Toni-I-Hight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LR5jgCm_M4U) by the band The Arrivals.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the word but I couldn't find it. It's such an effective word, I wonder why it isn't used much anymore?

Comment: @DisplayName - You're welcome. Still I wonder if many native speakers of English know that verb, I'll have to do some field research. :)

Comment: I'm a native English speaker. I've never heard of this word (although I like it!) and it is _definitely_ archaic. But @DisplayName the reason why it's not in use is clear from examples like "Childe Harold he was hight" (from http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hight?s=t); it's really a drop-in replacement for "called," and the entire "I am called" construction is absent from modern spoken English. But as to why that disappeared I have no clue

Comment: @ssdecontrol: I occasionally hear "I go by" or "you can call me" which seem close to the "I'm called" idiom from other languages, but both are a little bit more wordy.

YellowSky: Thanks for that -- It's news to me; I'll have to see if I can revive it in daily usage. :)

Comment: @ssdecontrol: has "I'm called Steve" simply been replaced by "I'm Steve", or are the two separate? The latter is used to mean both, "My name is Steve" and also, "That Steve you're aware of: I am he." Perhaps that leaves less room for "called".

Comment: @SteveJessop no native English speaker, at least in the United States, would say "I'm called Steve." The passive voice implies some degree of removal from the speaker, in that "_other_ people call me Steve." Consider the difference between "I am Ishmael" or "My name is Ishmael" and "Call me Ishmael" (the actual opening sentence of _Moby Dick_). The latter explicitly connotes that the narrator might not in fact be named Ishmael. I imagine the phrase dropped out of casual use when it acquired that connotation.

Comment: @Adrian both phrases would usually be reserved for giving a nickname, or a short name, or some name that isn't actually your name, but that you would prefer people use.

Comment: There is a material difference in meaning to say what your official name is (parents name, birth certificates, married name, stage name) verses the names you may go by. I have two friends who in the companies they work go by their preferred name not the name on their birth certificates. Chinese friends and colleagues have two names, an English one and a Chinese one. It's important to know when a person is asserting the name they choose or their "legal" name e.g. "My name is Priyanka but you can call me Pinky" clarifies both legal name and preferred name.

Comment: As a native speaker, I *have* encountered the "I height" construction, but extremely rarely - it might have been in a novel purporting to take place in the middle ages (or similar fantasy setting).  It's not a word I'd remember out of context, and I'd certainly look oddly at anyone using it.

Comment: Interestingly, *cite* **does** derive from the same root, and is most definitely used... although not the same sense at all.  [http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cite]

Comment: I'd be inclined to go with @slebetman's answer -- in colloquial (or even semi-formal) usage, "I'm Doktor J" is usually sufficiently clear. It's neat to know that we do have such a construct though!

Answer (score 13):

From my understanding of the other answers, I think English does have this idiom. Only, instead of a "word", in English "nothing at all" is used (or if you're a programmer, the empty string).

The Swedish phrase:

```
Jag heter XX
```

is translatable to English as:

```
I am called XX
```

But this is uncommon in spoken English. Instead of directly translating "heter" to "called", in spoken English it is often expressed as "" (nothing at all):

```
I am XX
```

or

```
I'm XX
```

So the idiom does exist. But instead of using a word, English uses the first person form of the verb "to be" (the word "am") as the mechanism.

Comment: My feeling is that "called" is closer to "kallas för" in Swedish. Difference between your given name and what you are referred to. i.e My name is Douglas. I am called Doug.

Comment: @ViktorMellgren I'm not referring to nuance of usage - just grammar. The grammatical construct exists in English though the "word" is often completely left out of the sentence in normal speech. Kind of like the verb "to be" in English, the concept and grammar construct of the verb "to be" exists but is either replaced by different words depending on context or completely removed from the sentence.

Comment: You are correct, I missed the whole point :)

Answer (score 9):

English does have a word for it, it's *called*.

e.g.

Swedish: `Jag heter Danny`

English: `I'm called Danny`

Although `I'm Danny`, or `My name's Danny` sounds less 'weird' to me.

Comment: While this does convey the same meaning, I believe the core question is about the absence of a single word. I think "I'm called" is more related to the French "Je m'mapelle" than to the Swedish "Jag heter" or the German "Ich heiße".

Comment: agree with SixthOfFour. "I'm called" is more of how poeple.. uh... *call* me, not necessarily my real name as my parents gave to me. One could call you "Dan" for "Danny" as a nickname, but that is not your real name. So "called" is not what TO searches for.

Comment: @Sempie I've heard that using "called" for a simple statement of someone's name is more common in British english.

Comment: Proper Dutch translation of "I'm called Danny" would be "Ik wordt Danny genoemd". The dutch verb "heten" is the same as "to hight" (already mentioned above).

Comment: @Tonny d'oh! I'll edit my answer to use another language, thanks.

Comment: I think *I'm called ...* would correspond to *Jag kallas ...* in Swedish.

Comment: @SixthOfFour but the OP puts as an example "me llamo" which is two words. "Yo me llamo" is a literal translation of "Je m'appelle", with the only difference that in Spanish the subject (Yo) is usually omitted because it is evident from the conjugation of the verb.

Comment: @abl The following is my interpretation, and I may be wrong. From the OP's profile page, it's clear that (s)he is Swedish. (S)He also claims to speak "very, very little Icelandic and Spanish", and I believe the reference to the Spanish "me ilamo" is simply a confusion due to the omitted subject. I still believe that the question is about a literal translation of "att heta", and until the OP says I'm wrong, I'll continue believing that.

Comment: @SixthOfFour Makes sense.

Comment: @Tonny: the "proper" translation of "I'm called John" in Dutch is "ik heet Jan". _Literal_, but non-idiomatic versions are "ik wordt Jan genoemd" and the English "I hight John". Translation is about more than translating words :)

Answer (score 3):

The question was, '*Why* does English not have a version of... heter'. Why does any change happen in languages? As others have said, there used to be one. In Old English you could say, 'Đa deor hie hatađ hranas' (The animals they called reindeer), but by the Middle Ages *hatan* had become *hight* and then died out, presumably because the alternatives became more popular.

Incidentally, in Barnsley people would ask, 'What do they call you?' rather than 'What are you called?' but that is a regional variation.

Answer (score 3):

The normal English (as spoken in England) is 'I'm called'. From the responses given so far I am very surprised to discover this is not used in some american dialects but certainly it is very common in standard English as spoken in England.